# XML parsing with Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am anewbie to the ELK stack and am  trying to process the below sample  XML file with Logstash

```
<Book:Body>
    <Book:Head>
        <bookname>Book:Name</bookname>
            <ns:Hello xmlns:ns="www.example.com">
                <ns:BookDetails>
                    <ns:ID>123456</ns:ID>
                    <ns:Name>ABC</ns:Name>
                </ns:BookDetails>
        </ns:Hello xmlns:ns="www.example.com">
    </Book:Head>
</Book:Body>
```

I am using the below conf to process the data:

```
input{ 
        file{ 
                path =>"/opt/data/book3.xml"
                                codec => multiline { 
                                pattern =>"<Book:Body>" 
                                negate => "true" 
                                what => "previous"} 
        }
} 

filter { 

                xml { 
                        store_xml => "false" 
                        source => "message" 
                        remove_namespaces => "true" 

                       xpath => [ 
                "/Body/Head/Hello/BookDetails/ID/text()", "ID", 
                "/Body/Head/Hello/BookDetails/Name/text()", "Name" 
                ] 
                    } 

                mutate { 
                        add_field => ["IDIndexed", "%{ID}"] 
                        add_field => ["NameIndexed", "%{Name}"] 
                        } 
} 
output{ 
        elasticsearch {hosts=>"localhost"} 
                stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
        }
```

i have enabled verbose mode for Logstash and there is no error being displayed but the output stops at below point

```
Starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>1, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>125, :level=>:info}
Pipeline main started
```

I have ensured that the file is being read only once

Appreciate any help on this

Comment: Check your XPath. It is without any namespace

Answer (score 0):

Using the multiline filter and XML is a bit tricky and not very stable. I recommend keeping it simple, making sure there are no new lines in the file, and then trying to use the XML filter.